# coffeescript file compiles, but gets "error: unmatched OUTDENT" when executed

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I have a file that compiles perfectly fine with `coffee -c app.coffee` or `--print`, but when I execute it with `coffee app.coffee` I get an unmatched outdent error.

Furthermore, the unmatched outdent is always at the exact same file location (line 109 column 16), **regardless** of what actual code is there. That is,

1. I run `coffee app.coffee`
2. It reports

   ```
   app.coffee:109:16: error: unmatched OUTDENT
   user.destroy()
          ^
   ```
3. I move my code around (insert some empty lines higher in the file)
4. I run `coffee app.coffee`
5. It reports

   ```
   app.coffee:109:16: error: unmatched OUTDENT
   user.setPassword(req.body.password).then () ->
            ^
   ```

And yes, that error indicator is pointing to a random character.

As I said above, this file compiles perfectly with `coffee -c app.coffee`.

Is this a bug in the `coffee` executable? What could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was actually a bug in how `coffee` was reporting the error.

The error was in a different file which was merely imported by `app.coffee`.

Issue opened: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/3239